# Getting SUM of Total items in PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

The tables are:

```
Orders
-----------
user_id
state


Items
-----------
order_id
product_id
total

Products
----------
user_id


Users
---------
name
email
```

Relationships are as follows:

```
User
has_many :products

Order
has_many :items
belongs_to :users

Product
has_many :items
belongs_to :user

Item
belongs_to :items
```

I want to get the sum of items.total per user that owns the product

I currently have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT *, SUM(items.total) as totalprice 
FROM "orders" 
INNER JOIN "items" ON "items"."order_id" = "orders"."id"
INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."id" = "items"."product_id"
INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "products"."user_id"
WHERE "orders"."state" = 'complete'
GROUP BY users.id
```

OR

```
Order.complete.joins(:items => {:product => :user}).select("*, SUM(items.total) as totalprice").group('users.id')
```

The above doesn't work. I feel that this should be easy.

Comment: "*doesn't work*" is not a valid Postgres error message.

Comment: PG::Error: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block <-- this the error

Comment: That is not the error message related to your query. It's a result of a previous error.

Comment: I am sorry but that's the only query and that's the only error. It doesn't make much sense to me too. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In group by queries you need to include all columns that are not aggregated in the group by clause.  If you change the query to this you may have better luck

```
SELECT users.id, SUM(items.total) as totalprice 
FROM "orders" 
INNER JOIN "items" ON "items"."order_id" = "orders"."id"
INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."id" = "items"."product_id"
INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "products"."user_id"
WHERE "orders"."state" = 'complete'
GROUP BY users.id
```

if you want more columns in the output, add them to the select line and to the group by line